# Excel VBA - compare cell values when other values in row meet criteria

Tags: excel, vba

There is data in columns A through E. What I want to do is compare the values in column E when columns A, B, C, and D are the same, and to add a value of X to the row in column F if these conditions are met. I want to mark only those that have a mismatch in column E, but when I mark one row all the rows with the same A, B, C, and D values should be marked.

For example, if A, B, C, and D are equal for the first three rows, I want to compare these entries. Since there is a mismatch in E3 when compared to E1 or E2, I want F1 through F3 to show as X. Since A, B, C, and D are equal in rows 4 and 5 but E4 and E5 match, I want it to ignore those cells.

What I have now is:

```
Sub Compare()

Worksheets(Sheet1).Activate
        For w = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For v = -10 To 10
        If Sheet1.Cells(w, "A").Value = Sheet1.Cells(w + v, "A").Value And Sheet1.Cells(w, "B").Value = Sheet1.Cells(w + v, "B").Value And Sheet1.Cells(w, "C").Value = Sheet1.Cells(w + v, "C").Value And Sheet1.Cells(w, "D").Value = Sheet1.Cells(w + v, "D").Value And Sheet1.Cells(w, "E").Value <> Sheet1.Cells(w + v, "E").Value Then
        Sheet1.Cells(w, "F").Value = "X"
        End If
        Next v
        Next w


End Sub
```

But it won't run. What do I need to change to get it working?

Comment: Does this need to be VBA? You could accomplish this with a formula.  In cell F1, use this formula and copy down: `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1,D:D,D1,E:E,E1)<>COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1,D:D,D1),"X","")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It does need to be in VBA though.

Comment: Then use `.Formula = ...`?  Taking a formula and applying in VBA is relatively trivial. Worst case, use the Macro Recorder to see how to do it.

Comment: This has helped a lot, thank you tigeravatar and BruceWayne. However, I do have an issue that I think may be caused by some of the data being asterisks. It looks like when one of the variables it is checking is an asterisk and there are other entries otherwise the same, it is comparing the whole group. Do you know what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed a lot. Also in your question talking about checking 3 lines so I set a variable `vrange=3`

```
 Sub Compare()
    Dim crit As Boolean
    vrange = 3
   'Sheet1.Activate
   Endi = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            For r = 1 To Endi
              vmin = WorksheetFunction.max(1, r - vrange) - r
              vmax = WorksheetFunction.min(Endi, r + vrange) - r
               For v = vmin To vmax
                crit = True
                For c = 1 To 4
                 crit = crit And Sheet1.Cells(r, c).value = Sheet1.Cells(r + v, c).value
                Next c
                If crit And Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).value <> Sheet1.Cells(r + v, 5).value Then
                 Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).value = "X"
                End If
               Next v
            Next r


    End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Your code was very easy to follow so I was able to modify it to fit my needs perfectly.